# Upgrading an MDI application with MFC Ribbon

Tags: mfc

I have an old style MFC MDI application. Now that VS 2010 has included a ribbon in VC++, I would like to upgrade my application with MFC ribbons. I also would like to give the user an option to retain the old style if he prefers to. That is the user should be able to switch between the classic view and the modern ribbon view while the application is running. Could you help me with achieving this please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is on best walkthrough given by MSDN [Walkthrough: Updating the MFC Scribble Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983935.aspx#addRibbon)  which may help you else provide your code or where exactly you are stuck.